# operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required - C

Tags: c, integer, type-conversion, void

Im using this method

```
void * col_check(void * params) {
parameters * data = (parameters *) params;
int startRow = data->row;
int startCol = data->col;
int *colm = malloc(9);
for (int i = startCol; i < 9; ++i) {
    int col[10] = {0};
    for (int j = startRow; j < 9; ++j) {
        int val = data->arr1[j][i];
        if (col[val] != 0) {
            colm[i]=i;
        }
        else{
            col[val] = 1;
        }
    }
}
return colm;    
}
```

i want to get the values in the colm array to the main program. So im using the below lines to do so. basically what the colm array stores are the column indexes of the arr1 which is not valid according to sudoku rules. (not important).

```
parameters * param10 = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));
    param10->row = 0;
    param10->col = 0;
    param10->arr1 = arr1;

void * cols;

pthread_create(&thread_10, NULL, col_check, (void *) param10);
pthread_join(thread_10, &cols);

printf("Calculating column validity please wait.\n");
    sleep(mdelay);

int c;
int value= (int)cols[1];
```

i get the error "operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required" when i try to get the value in cols[1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-ZflH_obS4QmtOVHF3SDRVMnc) to the variable "value". What am i doing wrong ? any suggestions?  Full code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-ZflH_obS4QmtOVHF3SDRVMnc)

Comment: First of all your `malloc(9)` in `col_check` should be `malloc(sizeof(int) * 9)`

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
Constraints
1
One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other
expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.*

Comment: `calloc(9, sizeof(int))` would be preferable.

Comment: what is the definition of the `struct parameters'?`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: this line: `void * cols;` should really be: `int * cols;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `(int)cols[1]` the `(int)` part has lower precedence than the `[1]` part, so the compiler tries to evaluate `cols[1]` first.

Then the compiler cannot calculate `cols[1]` because `void*` does not point to an item of a known size.  If the compiler does not know how large `cols[0]` is, then how can it figure out where `cols[1]` is?

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but what you *probably* want is `int value = ((int*)cols)[1];`

Comment: thanks this is what was wrong. fixed and now the error doesnt not appear. anyhow im trying to check if value variable is null. im trying to do it with if(value==NULL)  it seems to be wrong . do you have any comment on that ?

Comment: `NULL` expands to `0`, so `if( value == NULL )` is essentially checking whether `value` is `0`. That's not what you want.  Also, `value` cannot be null, because only a pointer can be null, and `value` it is not a pointer, it is an `int`. What you probably want to do is check whether `cols` is null before attempting to read the value pointed by it.

Comment: how would you check that  ? (cols==NULL) ? , im not sure how to do that since im very new to C.

Comment: You just saved my life. I'm using Pthreads and my `void*` parameter in my thread function was an `int` array when called. I could NOT cast to a simple `int`, kept saying the `void*` was incompatible with `int`. But changing it to `((int*)array)[i]` changed everything!

Answer (score 1):

@Mike Nakis already provided a good answer, I will fix one of your syntax errors.

When you are declaring colm as a pointer of integers column matrix you are doing it wrong. `malloc` is defined as:

`void* malloc( size_t size );`

You only allocates 9 consecutive bytes, if you want 9 consecutive bytes of ints, you would have to do either:

`int *colm = malloc(sizeof(int)*9);`

or:

`int *colm = calloc(9, sizeof(int));`

The latter is more preferable, in my point of view. But either do the same thing, except that [calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) also initializes all bytes in the allocated storage to zero.

Comment: Thanks yes Mike's answer worked and i followed your suggestion as well.